# WPF - Is there a way to cause a UI element to lose focus without changing the focus to something else?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus, custom-controls

I would like to add an IsFocused property to a custom textbox that I am working on, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken something always has to be in focus. That being said you can Focus to a label or some non-editable/non-selectable element if you need. Or you can focus another application.

In general, however, something is always in focus.