# Detect click out of the control in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, c#-3.0

For begin I want to describe my problem for you.

I want to show huge number of records in something like combobox, but because combobox isn't a good solution for displaying such huge number of data hence I simulate combobox behaviour with DataGridView.

Now my problem is when user click out of DataGridView , DataGridView should be closed(like combobox when it isn't collapsed or dropped). but there is a lot of other control on the form and I cant handle click event of all of them to detect that out of DataGridView  has been clicked.

to sum up I look for a simple solution for invisible DataGridView if user click outta that .

at the end I know a vague awareness of MouseCapture property of controls but I cant work with that and  I dont know how can I use that for handle my desire.I am appreciate you if you can help me for using MouseCapture for solving this problem or giving another solution.

thanks for you

Comment: obviously Lost focus and leave isnt my asnwer

Comment: I think the drop-down portion of the ComboBox control is actually in a separate window from the text box.  You could try something similar: show your DataGridView in a separate, dedicated window, and hide that window when it is deactivated.

Comment: Perhaps there is a simple solution, but I am a bit rusty in WinForms, so for now can only suggest something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991044/winforms-intercepting-mouse-event-on-main-form-first-not-on-controls

Comment: @adv12 how can I detect it is deactivated? I dont see activate property or event on datagridview

Comment: @hamed, you listen for the [Deactivate event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on the containing form, not on the DataGridView.

Comment: If I remember right from implementing something similar years ago, you may also need to do some P/Invoke with the native Windows `ShowWindow` function to get all the desired properties for the containing form.  I don't remember what I couldn't do just with .NET functionality, but there was something missing.

Comment: @adv12 yeap, I saw similar solution  but it is very difficult and complex, also I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761786/how-can-a-control-handle-a-mouse-click-outside-of-that-control that give simple solution but i cant utilize that

Comment: dear @adv12 do you saw this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761786/how-can-a-control-handle-a-mouse-click-outside-of-that-control?noredirect=1&lq=1   if you understand what I should do from that link please describe that for me.

Comment: Hi @hamed, did implementing the custom control help with this problem? Let me know if you're still having a problem. If not, please mark my answer accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter give me more time for test that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom control should make this fairly simple, especially if this is a top-level control (i.e. directly in your main window). You can listen for click events on the parent object and use the `ClientRectangle` property to determine if the click was outside the `DataGridView`.

Here's a basic example:

```
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView, IMessageFilter {
    public MyDataGridView() {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        this.HandleDestroyed += (sender, args) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x201) {
            if (!ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition))) {
                Hide();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Peter I test your solution, I again face with my problem. I said I have several Control on my form then as you said I create a custom control  and put that on form but because we monitor Parent.MouseClick only if you click on parent form we detect click out of custom control , and if user click on other controls on parent form custom control doesnt sense that click .

Comment: Hi @Hamed, I understand now. I think this new version should work

Comment: dear @pete this new solution work properly. you are great.

Comment: Thanks, Peter your answer is helpful for me to archive my requirement, thanks for sharing your valuable answer with us...@